# Extract pixel values and its category using R

Tags: raster, r, extract

I've been using this script for a long time. This code creates a DataFrame that contains the pixel values of each band of a RasterStack that overlaps with a SpatialPolygonDataFrame or a SpatialPointsDataFrame. It also assigns to each pixel a "class" category defined in the "class" field of the polygon or point attribute table. However the code is very slow. What improvement could you make to make it more efficient?

I have also observed strange behavior. I am working with a WIN10 Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-8565U CPU @ 1.80GHz 2.00 GHz, 16 Gb RAM. However, running the code on a much lower machine makes the code run much faster.

```
# img = RasterStack
# trainData = SpatialPolygonDataFrame with the 'class' field

library(raster)
library(rgdal)

img <- stack("D:/img.tif")
trainData <- readOGR("D:/training_polygons.shp")
responseCol <- "class"

df_Train = data.frame(matrix(vector(), nrow = 0, ncol = length(names(img)) + 1))   
for (i in 1:length(unique(trainData[[responseCol]]))){
  category <- unique(trainData[[responseCol]])[i]
  categorymap <- trainData[trainData[[responseCol]] == category,]
  dataSet <- extract(img, categorymap)
  if(is(trainData, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")){
    dataSet <- cbind(dataSet, class = as.numeric(rep(category, nrow(dataSet))))
    df_Train <- rbind(df_Train, dataSet[complete.cases(dataSet),])
  }
  if(is(trainData, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")){
    dataSet <- dataSet[!unlist(lapply(dataSet, is.null))]
    dataSet <- lapply(dataSet, function(x){cbind(x, class = as.numeric(rep(category, nrow(x))))})
    df <- do.call("rbind", dataSet)
    df_Train <- rbind(df_Train, df)
  }
}
df_Train$class <- as.factor(df_Train$class)
```

Comment: It is very difficult to comment without example data. I doubt that you even need a loop. Can you improve your question by including example data, either using data that ships with R or created with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the `ExtractTrainData` package that allows to perform exactly this operation faster and more efficiently. Here's an example:

```
if (!require("ExtractTrainData")) install.packages("ExtractTrainData")
library(ExtractTrainData)

# example with toy data
img <- stack(system.file("extdata","ras.tif", package = "ExtractTrainData"))
shp <- shapefile(system.file("extdata","poly_shp.shp", package = "ExtractTrainData"))

# extract pixel values and category using ExtractByPoly
Out.colName <- In.colName <- "Id"
df <- ExtractByPoly(img, shp, In.colName, Out.colName)
```

*CRAN link:* https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ExtractTrainData/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your loop part is "growing" objects. (https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf, page 12). When you use `rbind(df_train, df)` within a loop it has to duplicate the entire object on each iteration. You may speed things up by *pre-allocating* a vector, e.g. `my_list <- vector('list', n)` where `n` is the size of `length(unique(trainData[[responseCol]]))`; then, on each iteration assign output to each item: `my_list[1] = df`, for finally using `do.call(rbind, my_list)`.